# How to run and execute a makefile C

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile for my program. It is so difficult because i've read a lot of guide but none is clear. I have 3 files : `main.c` , `library.c` , `library.h` . Main.c and library.c depend on library.h . The structure of my directory project is formed by :
MyProject directory -> Build directory and Exercise1 directory -> all of my files . In compiler I wrote `make` and it compiled ; then when I write  `make execute` command, it gives me this error:

```
cd ../build; ./test
Error: No such file or directory
makefile:23: recipe for target 'execute' failed
make: *** [execute] Error 1
```

**MAKEFILE**

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
ODIR=../build
DIR = build

.PHONY: all

all: main.o library.o test

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -std=c99 -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

library.o: library.c library.h
    $(CC) -std=c99 -c -o $(ODIR)/$@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main.o: main.c library.h
    $(CC) -std=c99 -c -o $(ODIR)/$@ $< $(CFLAGS)

test: $(ODIR)/library.o $(ODIR)/main.o
    $(CC) -std=c99 -o $(ODIR)/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

execute:
    cd $(ODIR); ./test

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704161/getting-an-error-while-a-program-in-c-using-makefile

Comment: In 
execute:
    cd $(ODIR); ./test
what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
execute:
    cd $(ODIR); ./test
```

tell `make` that, when you give the command `make execute`, it should change the working directory to `$(ODIR)` and then execute `./test`, which means to execute the file `test` in the current working directory. However, there is no file `test` in the `$(ODIR)` directory because you have not built it yet.

You can make that file by executing `make test`, but that is a bad way to do it. It is better to tell `make` that the `execute` target depends on `$(ODIR)/test`:

```
execute: $(ODIR)/test
    cd $(ODIR); ./test
```

Then we should change the rule for `test` to `$(ODIR)/test`:

```
$(ODIR)/test: $(ODIR)/library.o $(ODIR)/main.o
    $(CC) -std=c99 -o $(ODIR)/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Next, delete the rule for `all` and the `.PHONY` rule. A rule for `all` should be used when a makefile can make several different final targets, like `ProgramA`, `ProgramB`, and `ProgramC`, and you want one target that makes all of them. It should not be used to make all of the intermediate object files for a target. The intermediate files should arise out of the rules for building a final target.

Then delete the rules for `library.o` and `main.o`. Those are names for files in the current directory, but you are building in `$(ODIR)`. We will let the pattern rule for `$(ODIR)/%.o` build those.

But we need to fix the pattern rule. It uses `DEPS`, but that is not defined. Add a line above that says what all the object files depend on:

```
DEPS=library.h
```

Nothing in the makefile uses `DIR`, so delete the line `DIR = build`.

Finally, you might want to put the `execute` target first, so that it is the default. Then your makefile is:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
ODIR=../build
DEPS=library.h

execute: $(ODIR)/test
    cd $(ODIR); ./test

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -std=c99 -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/test: $(ODIR)/library.o $(ODIR)/main.o
    $(CC) -std=c99 -o $(ODIR)/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o
```

You might also change the command for `clean` to remove `test`:

```
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o $(ODIR)/test
```

Comment: using your `code` it gives me the same error of before: `cd ../build; ./test
Error: No such file or directory
makefile:7: recipe for target 'execute' failed
make: *** [execute] Error 1 `

Comment: @cocoricò: Make the `../build` directory first. There are ways to incorporate that into the makefile, but they involve further complications.

Comment: i've already created build directory. When I use make command , it inserts in build directory library.o main.o and test.exe but then it gives me  that error.

Comment: my folders are: MyProject , in which there are 'build' directory and 'exercise1', in exercise1 there are all my files.